# Angular 4 Redux select issue (basic)

Tags: angular, redux, angular-redux

I am still in the early stages of learning Angular 4 and Redux. I have a component that gets information from the store. It works fine IN THE VIEW. But when I try to access the same information from within the component, I get an object instead of the value.

Here is my component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux'; 
import { AppState } from '../../reducers/reducer';
import { QuizService } from '../../services/quiz.service';  
import { clearQuiz } from '../../actions/actions'; 

@Component({ 
    selector: 'quiz', 
    templateUrl: './quiz.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['./quiz.component.css']
})

export class Quiz {
    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<AppState>, private service: QuizService) {}

    @select('currentQuiz') currentQuiz;
    @select('quizLength') quizLength; 
    @select('sessionId') sessionId; 

    handleClose() {
        console.log("CLOSE", this.sessionId )
        this.service.deleteSession(this.sessionId)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.ngRedux.dispatch(clearQuiz())
            })
            , error => {
                console.error(error); 
            }
    }
}
```

The "console.log("CLOSE", this.sessionId )" line does not return the value stored in the store. Instead, I get this:

```
CLOSE AnonymousSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
```

How do you get the data off of these objects within the class? In the view, if I add "| async" after the value, they show up. But I can not get the values from within the actual component class. Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the selected slices of the state, because when you `@select` from the store you do not get a value but an `Observable`. That's why you have to use the `async` pipe in your template. It automatically does the subscribing for you.

You could for example subscribe in the `OnInit` Hook and assign it to a field. It's good practice to give fields the suffix `$` if they are Observables. I've assumed that you have an interface `IQuiz` for the data model of `currentQuiz`. If the variable name is the same as the store property (ignoring $), you can omit it with the `@select`:

```js
@select() currentQuiz$: Observable<IQuiz>;
currentQuiz: IQuiz;

// ...

ngOnInit() {
  this.currentQuiz$.subscribe(currentQuiz => this.currentQuiz = currentQuiz)
}
```

When your store is updated, `this.currentQuiz` will automatically be reassigned.